# Recreating diagrams

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

If I want to recreate the diagram I made with dragging elements using jsplumb, I can send the anchor's positions.. But I was wondering how can I send the exact position of the draggable element. In the beginning I tell where to place these elements but in the proces of drag and drop I move them around the canvas and then when I 'save' the diagram I want to memorize the current postion of the element, not the starting.

Comment: I did it by saving the elements position & offset. `$(element).offset()` and `$(element).position()` are your friends to get the final position of the dragged element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just trigger something like that, when you press the save button:

```
$('.your elements').each(function(){
    var elementPositionX = $(this).css('left');
    var elementPositionY = $(this).css('top');
}
```